# How to fill a Combo Box on C# with the namefiles from a Dir?

Tags: c#, combobox, directory

I hope you can help me with this problem.

I've been trying to fill a combobox with the namefiles  of a specific directory. This DIR will be always the same so it will be the same routine always.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initialize do this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Testing");

        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.txt");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    mycombobox.items.add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are using WPF

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="DirectoriesComboBox" Width="100" Height="25"></ComboBox>
</Grid>

string [] array = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test");
DirectoriesComboBox.ItemsSource = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding a reference to system.IO and using this code:
(DDLFolder is you dropdown list, and if you are writing an ASP.Net application for getting the path use Server.Mappath("~/yourpath"))

```
DirectoryInfo df = new DirectoryInfo(userFolderPath);
DDLFolder.Items.Clear();
DDLFolder.Items.Add("Root");
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in df.GetDirectories())
{
DDLFolder.Items.Add(d.Name);
}
```